# ItemDroppedOnTarget in DragDropTarget should have target element

Tags: c#, silverlight, drag-and-drop, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-toolkit

I'm using `DragDropListBoxTarget` control from `Silverlight Toolkit` to support the drag and drop behavior. But I'm facing with a problem with this control.

It's hard to get hold of target element on which the item is dropped. It is a must to have thing in ItemDroppedOnTarget event arguments.

When I drag an item, I need when the user drops it, an intermediate event should modify the target Item. But I can't find the way to implement it.

Am I using the right control, or what another alternatively do I have?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I ended up using [this drag-drop tool](http://code.google.com/p/silverlightdragdrop/). I recompiled the source for Silverlight 5. It lets me know the target. I was also lazy and still wanted the ghost-drag pic of whatever you're dragging when using the toolkit DragDropTarget controls, so I kept my source wrapped in that and also wrapped in the new drag-drop tool.

The way I defined the dragging:

```
<toolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget AllowedSourceEffects="Copy">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UnitOfWork.Templates}" Width="130" Height="360" BorderThickness="0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <dd:DragSource>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="120"/>
                    </dd:DragSource>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</toolkit:ListBoxDragDropTarget>

<dd:DropTarget Grid.Row="2" AllowDrop="True" OnDropped="Target_OnDropped">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="98" Height="30">                
        <TextBlock Text="Drop Here" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
</dd:DropTarget>
```

This way keeps the dragging ghost that the **ListBoxDragDropTarget** creates, while allowing me to use the **dd:DragSource** and **dd:DropTarget** controls to allow finer-grained drag-drops.